# CodeWars challenge. Which test is causing the fail?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone find out what is wrong with this code? I run the code on CodeWars and pass every test except one... sadly it does not display what the input was for that specific test so it is very difficult to figure it out.

Here are the challenge instructions:

The new "Avengers" movie has just been released! There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollars bill. A "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.

Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.

Can Vasya sell a ticket to each person and give the change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people follow in the line?
Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to each person and give the change. Otherwise return NO.

**I found that the code works for ALL tests if I swap the check for amount50 >= 1 and amount25 >= 1 with the amount25 >= 3 but I am not sure WHY this works.**

```
function tickets(peopleInLine){
  let amount25 = 0;
  let amount50 = 0;
  let amount100 = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < peopleInLine.length; i++){

    if(peopleInLine[i] === 100){
      if(amount25 >= 3){
        amount25 -= 3;
        amount100++;
      }else if(amount25 >= 1 && amount50 >= 1){
       amount25 -= 1;
       amount50 -= 1;
       amount100++;
      }else{
        return "NO";
      }
    }

    if(peopleInLine[i] === 50){
      if(amount25 >= 1){
        amount25--;
        amount50++;
      } else {
       return "NO";
      }
    }

    if(peopleInLine[i] === 25){
      amount25++;
    }
  }
  return "YES";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On Codewars you can put console.log statements (or equivalent statements in languages other than JavaScript) in your code to print the input parameters or other variables when you're having trouble figuring out what is going wrong in your code or with your assumptions about the input. I just did this with your code and saw that the test your code is failing on is [ 25, 25, 25, 25, 50, 100, 50 ], so that should show you exactly why your code would be failing when in response to getting a $100 you first try to return three $25s as change instead of checking for a $50 and $25 first -- you receive four $25s, one of which you give as change to the first person with a $50, but then because you give the remaining three $25s (rather than the $50 and one $25) as change to the person with the $100, you no longer have a $25 to make change for the last person's $50.